# Excel Search array formula not working for all parts of array

Tags: arrays, excel, search

I would appreciate your assistance with a search formula I am working on.

For some reason, the search portion of my formula only works for "`Mr.`", not the other salutations

What I have currently is:

```
=IF(OR(SUM(LEN(C8)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C8," ","")))/LEN(" ")<=2,ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Mr.","Mrs.","Ms."},C8)))
```

*[the formula continues after this, but the part I am having trouble with is above]*

Can someone provide an explanation why my Search only works for "`Mr.`" and not the other salutations?  I am also open to suggestions for formula improvements.

Many thanks!

Comment: could you supply some test data and expected to results to go with this please?

Comment: Is your formula correctly written above?

Comment: In column C, a name is written, such as "Mr. Timony Lang", "Ms. Antonia Gilroy," or "Abraham Lewis".  I am trying to extract the Mr., Ms., or other salutation.  the part of the formula that is not working is: ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Mr.","Mrs.","Ms."},C8)  It only searches for Mr.   Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this bit

```
SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Mr.","Mrs.","Ms."},C8)))>0
```

instead of

```
ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Mr.","Mrs.","Ms."},C8)
```